# How can i convert the string with special characters into json object

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to parse the string and convert it in to `JSONObject`.But it is not converted and giving the error like

```
"07-28 11:36:47.674: WARN/System.err(6050): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 3136 of {"data":[{""...."(there is my data)
```

First i thought there is some special characters like `~,@,%,&` and replace the characters with `" "` but there is no result and giving the same error.

And i modified the web services data by encoding with `UTF-8` format. and i used the code to get decode the `UTF-8` formatted data in my application.here is my code:

```
                           HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
               HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
               HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
           params.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue",false);
               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
               HttpGet httpget =new htpGet("http://www.mylink.com"+todaydate);


                   try
                   {
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        jsonText = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
                        Log.d("TEST", jsonText);   /this is the result string

                              }
                   catch (Exception e)
                   {
                   }

 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonText.toString());
```

Here i cannot convert the string(`jsonText`) into `json object(jobj)`.But in **logcat** it is displaying the string `jsonText` perfectly. Is there any suggestion to get the data as json object.

I need to use the `Json object` in my application.

Comment: Have you checked your json string with a json validator (e.g. [here](http://jsonlint.com/))?

Comment: May be json string is badly formed.

Comment: yes my json string formate is not correct.I find this by scessor comment. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the JSON data is valid and no special characters are causing problems then "Unterminated string at character" could mean that you have not received the whole string.

You could prove this by checking a substring from the end and displaying that in logcat

If not then you need to start looking for the special characters again